# Visual Studio UML Sequence Diagram

Tags: c#, uml, sequence-diagram

I was wondering if there was a Sequence Diagram generator for C#?

Im using Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

If not is there a quick and simple software?

Im finding Enterprise Architect and Visio a bit too cryptic for a beginner.

I have found the Class Diagram feature on Visual Studio, which s very useful and am hoping for a equally useful simple program to generate Sequence Diagrams.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than products like Enterprise Architect, I don't know of a way to do it with VS2008.

OTOH, you can do it with VS2010.

Comment: When did Microsoft hire Rumplestiltskin?  I've been hearing this refrain since the announcement.  "Of course we/it can do that! You just have to install 2010."

Comment: @Kelly: what are you talking about? This functionality is there, in the box. I don't know if you need the "Ultimate" edition to get it, but it's there. I've seen it.

Comment: Please accept my apology. My comment wasn't directed to you or even VS2010 but moreso was a reaction to vendors who are more interested in pitching SharePoint 2010 then helping us with 2007 and its warts.  Their constant refrain is "You can do that in 2010" to most every question.

Comment: @Kelly: maybe it's true that you can do it "in 2010". Sometimes, you have to move forward in order to fix things.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your question into two parts:

1) are there tools for diagramming my C# code in UML
2) are any of those tools integrated into Visual Studio

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) is a standalone tool that does pretty good general UML diagrams without needing a huge enterprisey package.
[yuml.me](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/activity/draw) has a shorthand for online activity/sequence diagrams

I doubt either one helps with the second issue but I hope they help with the first issue.

Comment: In UML, **activity** and **sequence** diagrams are different beasts. yuml.me only supports **activity** of those two.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you ever choose to install VS2010 and would still like to create a sequence diagram from code:
1.  Open the source code of the method that you would like to generate from it the sequence diagram.
2.  Press the right mouse button on the method body and select ‘Generate Sequence Diagram’.
If you have a special folder for sequence diagrams:
3.  Deselect the ‘Add diagram to current project’.
4.  Save the diagram in right location (Sequence Diagrams) and add it to the Source Control. (We're working with TFS).